# mimic navController behavior of menu item in NavigationView for header views

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer, navigationview

**Is there any way to make header in navigationView behave like menu item in navigationView with navController?**
I have implemented a NavigationView in DrawerLayout following [Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/NavigationDrawer.md) on Material Component Github.
For the menu items in NavigationView, I set it up with navController like this.

```
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.signInFragment, // <- (Currently adding this)I want this to be placed at header in navigationView
            R.id.myFragment1, // < this is my home fragment where the app initially opened
            R.id.myFragment2,
            R.id.myFragment3,
            R.id.myFragment4,
            R.id.myFragment5
        ),
        drawerLayout
    )

    // handles navigation icon to be dynamically interchangeable accordingly
    // This allows NavigationUI to decide what label to show in the action bar
    // By using appBarConfig, it will also determine whether to
    // show the up arrow or drawer menu icon
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    binding.navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

then, I am trying to add signInFragment as part of header in the `navigationView` rather than a menu item. However, here comes my challenge. An instruction from Navigation Drawer doesn't seem to provide how to connect the header like how menu item does to use navigation feature, I think I need to do it manually. so I tried it by placing navigationUp() and popBackStack() together as [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/backstack#basic-behavior) says.

```
val headerView: View? = binding.navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
val sivProfile = headerView?.findViewById<ShapeableImageView>(R.id.siv_profile_picture)
val tvLogin = headerView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_login_email)
sivProfile?.setOnClickListener {
    navController.navigateUp()
    navController.popBackStack()
    navController.navigate(R.id.signInFragment)
    drawerLayout.close()
}
tvLogin?.setOnClickListener {
    navController.navigateUp()
    navController.popBackStack()
    navController.navigate(R.id.signInFragment)
    drawerLayout.close()
}
```

but the problem is, this implementation somehow messes up old behaviors.
*Old behavior* is to take users to myFragment1 from any other fragments by pressing back button besides from myFragment1(home fragment) itself.
*After that implementation*,

1. Visit signInFragment first, then visit other fragments. This step leaves back stacks of all history where I have visited. So the back button behavior is changed.
2. Once navigated to signInFragment, back button doesn't take a user to the myFragment1 which is my home fragment.

**Is there any way to make header in navigationView behave like menu item in navigationView with navController?**